# How to select fields from a json field

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm using Postgresql 9.5.4. How do I select a field from a json field? I tried

```
SELECT balance 
FROM json_each(SELECT data FROM oauth WHERE provider = 'plaid')
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT data->'balance' as balance FROM oauth WHERE provider = 'plaid'`

Comment: Please add some explanation along with your answer